# Не могу залить проект на гитхаб

Tags: git, github

Всем привет!
У меня проблема с гитом хочу залить проект на гитхаб,но появляется такая запись
Push failed Remote: Invalid username or password.
Данные в IntelliJ IDEA для гитхаба введены правильные в браузере в аккаунт захожу без проблем

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу запушить коммит на git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1302132/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-git)

Comment: Не нужно дублировать  один и тот же вопрос по несколько раз.