# Не могу запушить коммит на git

Tags: git, github

только начинаю работать с гитхаб и гит
Поменял глобально имя в гите после чего при попытке запушить коммит появилась ошибка
Push failed
Remote: Invalid username or password.
Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как можно это решить?

Comment: в аккаунт гихаба захожу нормально

Comment: я не вижу причин не верить сообщению. Если говорит, что неверное имя пользователя или пароль, значит, так оно и есть. Кстати, на гитхабе авторизацию по юзернейму/паролю или уже отключили или вот-вот отключат. Настраивайте соединение через токен.